# Populating text in report on promotional pricing if PO date falls in offer period

Tags: acumatica

I need to populate a textfield in PO report with a plain text "Promotional" if PO Order Date falls between the Promotional Pricing period (Between Effective and Expiration dates, both inclusive).

For Example,
Promotional Pricing is 
$0.50 between 8/16/2017 to 8/31/2017 and,
$9.30 between 9/4/2017 to 9/8/2017

PO Order is
Dated 8/23/2017 then text will NOT be printed
Dated 8/17/2017 then text will be printed
Dated 9/3/2017 then text will NOT be printed
Dated 9/6/2017 then text will be printed

[image]

I have included APVendorPrice table and joined with POLine on VendorID and InventoryID. I have Filtered with IsPromotional=1.

However, report considers only the first record of that particular Inventory while printing the text. Below is the code for printing text field.

```html
=IIf(([POOrder.OrderDate] >= [APVendorPrice.EffectiveDate] And [POOrder.OrderDate] <= [APVendorPrice.ExpirationDate]), Trim('PROMO ' + [APVendorPrice.EffectiveDate] + ' ' + [APVendorPrice.ExpirationDate]),'')
```

Ideally, it should check for all the Promotional Pricing table for that particular inventory and print the text accordingly.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Left Join POLine and APVendorPrice tables with InventoryID, VendorID and OrderDate GreaterOrEqual to EffectiveDate and OrderDate LessOrEqual to ExpirationDate. Add IsPromotional condition in visible expression of the textbox.